# Display Multiple pin on same LAT/LONG values

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to show pins on mapv2 of same lat/long values, but the pins are getting overlapped on one another. Id there any better way to display multiple pins at same lat/long when i have to display bunch of pins at the same location (Lat/Long).

Comment: Use `anchor(float u, float v)` of `MarkerOptions()` with different value for each marker, may be this could be a work around :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `anchor(float u, float v)` of `MarkerOptions()` to set different anchor for each `Marker`

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible, because just think in a common way, you have one latitude and longitude, means one point to put pin, so if you are push 1000 pins there then you can only see one only, because there is one predefined as well as perfect point.

Its not possible.

Comment: Using anchor(float u, float v) of MarkerOptions() solves the issue.