# How to Handle Multiple Location with Same Latitude and Longitude in Google Android Map V2

Tags: android, android-mapview

Am Using Google Map V2 in my Application.Here am getting Same Latitude and Longitude for different Location and Once i click that Overlay i have to show the Details one by one.Let Me Known to handle this in Google Android Map V2..?

Example :  i have two shop details (Shop name,Merchant Name and Address) but with same Latitude and Longitude.Here in Map only one Icon will shown,while clicking the Icon i have to show that two Shop details one by one.Hope you got my point right

Cheers
Shankar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889120/1939564

Comment: i don't think there is any same lat and lon for different locations. how is it possible.check your code. there must be some problem when fetching latlong.

Comment: Hi, i have two shop details (Shop name,Merchant Name and Address) but with same Latitude and Longitude.Here in Map only one Icon will show,while clicking the Icon i have to show that two Shop details one by one.Hope you got my point right..

Answer (score 0):

Use a marker clustering library like android-maps-extensions: https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions