# Differentiate two markers at same place in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-utils

Here in the code am displaying markers but if many markers have same latitude and logitude then the icons generated must have different colors or it must be moved a little bit so that we must be able to find that its in that location. Is it possible to do?

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point, TextView icTag) {
    Bitmap icBitmap = null;
    icGen.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_ORANGE);
    icGen.setContentRotation(0);
    icGen.setContentPadding(10,10,10,10);
    tvImage.setTypeface(imageFont);
    icGen.setContentView(tvImage);
    icBitmap = icGen.makeIcon();

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng)
            .snippet("" + snip).position(point)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromBitmap(icBitmap));
    marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

}
```

Comment: Use google maps clustering..

Comment: Why do you want to set multiple markers exactly at the same coordinates? Thats weird.

Comment: @NachoRamosSánchez See am listing all users available in a group w.r.t their locaton. If they are in same location then only the recent marker in array is visible other markers are available but visually we are not able to distinguish

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889120/1939564

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a bit of logic in your code so that older items are either bigger or with different colors or with different anchors.
Of course you need to check the distance of points before doing that, and i would suggest to use clustering which works fine for this kind of tasks