# Mulitple google map marker on same location

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am doing application based upon showing outlet of all the accessories items, Mall, petrol pump, restaurant,etc., Consider In the case of Mall, in mall there will be an many floor. So there might be change that two or more shops to have save same latitude and Longitude location. So my problem is, need to show multiple maker at a particular location if it is having more than one entry.

I am using Google map V2.

Please don't suggest Indoor map.

Comment: clustering is solution?

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889120/1939564

Comment: clustering will not work for this problem. Because, I am having more than marker on same latitude and longitude. Clustering is based upon Distance , Grid

Comment: [Have you tried anything ?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)